# strcat result used as a bash system call does not like ampersand

Tags: c, strcat

I am working on an embedded system using ash instead of bash and am trying to call a script from a cross-compiled C program.

It is working, but not in a background process like I am asking it. In fact, it seems like a strcat command is not working, but it beats me why.

Am rather new at C, it must be something obvious.

The code:

```
char mycall[230] = "/home/root/myscript.sh ";
char inbackground[3]= " &";


// buf is initiated and will be used as a parameter, string length is about 20 characters
strcat(buf,inbackground);
strcat(mycall,buf);

printf("%s", mycall);   // this will display the command and parameter that was stored with 
   // in buf correctly, but without the ampersand at the end
system(mycall); // executes correctly
```

Screen displays:

```
sh: syntax error: "&" unexpected
```

Why is it doing this?

Comment: if `buf` is "about 20 characters" it is already too short!

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that `buf` contains a newline (`'\n'`) character at the end.  Maybe some other non-displayable character.

You need to filter that unwanted stuff away.

Since we aren't shown exactly how `buf` is set up (or what ti's type is), it's also possible that whatever 1buf1 points to doesn't have enough room for the additional characters. you might want to rejigger your concatenations like so to avoid having to modify `buf`:

```
strcat(mycall,buf);
strcat(mycall,inbackground);
```